# Python "global" keyword doesn't work with "from ... import ..."

Tags: python, global

I'm using Python version 3.4.2 on Windows 8 and I've found that the "global" keyword doesn't work with "from ... import ..."

To test I wrote my code like this:

```
# In test1.py
a = 1
def aPlusPlus():
  global a
  a += 1
```

and this:

```
# In test2.py
from test1 import *
print(a)
aPlusPlus()
print(a)
```

And the result is:

```
> python3 test2.py
1
1
```

However, if I write `import test1`, `test1.a` and `test1.aPlusPlus()`, there result is:

```
> python3 test2.py
1
2
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: If you add a function to `test1.py` to `print a`, things may become slightly clearer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Globals are not shared between modules. Your `test2` namespace got its own indepdendent reference to the `1` value `a` references in the other module.

Setting `a` in `test1` then *rebinds* the `test.a` name to a new object (the `2` integer value), but the `test2.a` reference is not going to be updated.

Use a mutable object if you want to share data between modules; both modules can reference the same `list` or `dict` object, for example, and changes to values stored *in* those mutable structures then can be seen in both locations.